# OpenGL 3.0+: Orthographic Matrix does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, orthographic

Currently I'm developing a small Game Engine. I've done transformation, but including orthographic projection brokes a program and then sprite isn't rendering at all. Transformation class is just translating and scaling object and alone it works perfectly.

Orthographic Matrix creation:

```
Matrix Matrix::orthographic(const float & left, const float & right, const float & top, const float & bottom, const float & near, const float & far)
{
    Matrix m(0.0f);
    m.value[0][0] = 2 / (right - left);
    m.value[1][1] = 2 / (top - bottom);
    m.value[2][2] = 2 / (far - near);

    m.value[3][0] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    m.value[3][1] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    m.value[3][2] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    m.value[3][3] = 1;

    return m;
}
```

Creation of Transformation:

```
transformable = new Transformable(Vector3(10.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f), Vector3(64.f, 64.f, 0.0f));
```

Using of this Matrix:

```
shaderProgram->setMatrixUniform("projection", Matrix::orthographic(0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f));
```

Using Transformation:

```
shaderProgram->setMatrixUniform("transformation", transformable->getMatrix());
```

Could someone help me please? I've no idea where is my fault.

Comment: Its confusing you are saying perspective breaks programe but you have given code for orthographic projection?

Comment: @Rabbid76 My bad, wrong nomenclature.

Comment: Usually it has to be `-2 / (far - near)` instead of `2 / (far - near)`. In a [right handed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule), the view space z-axis points out of the viewport - usually.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Really? Thanks for tip <3

Comment: *"Transformation class is just translating and scaling object and alone it works perfectly."* The difference is that you have to draw the model in window coordinates, because of the orthographic projection. Does it work if you use an orthographic projection like this: `Matrix::orthographic(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f));`, what should be the same as using no projection at all?

Comment: Possibly `Matrix::orthographic(-800.0f/600.0f, 800.0f/600.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)`, is what you want to do.

Comment: I know the difference between drawing in ortho projection and without. I just noticed that transformation alone is working perfectly, so it's not transofmration's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it, Matrix contstructor was filling Matrix with strange numbers instead of 0, so i replaced

```
Matrix m(0.0f);
```

with

```
Matrix m;
```